# Tedious.js Unsupported Protocol

Tags: node.js, express, tedious

I am seeing the below error when trying to connect to a local sql server database using tedious. I have tried both using the IP address and localhost and it won't connect. TCP/IP is enabled for MSSQLSERVER in sql server configuration manager. I also verified that sql server browser is also running.

Error:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:1433 - 22996:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1942:

at ConnectionError (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
at Connection.socketError (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:56)
at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1405:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
code: 'ESOCKET'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kagetruckroutingappserver@0.0.0 start: node ./bin/www
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the kagetruckroutingappserver@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! Redacted
```

Code:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection; 
var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
console.log('start')
var config = {
  server: 'localhost',
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: 'redacted', // update me
      password: 'redacted' // update me
    },
    options: {
      encrypt: false, 
      cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
        minVersion: 'TLSv1'
    }
    }
  }
}
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    console.log('after connection variable')
    connection.connect();
    console.log('after connect')
    connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
      if (err) {
        console.log('Connection Failed');
        throw err;
      } 
        // If no error, then good to proceed.
        console.log("Connected");  
        
    });
```

### Edit - now getting a different error after changing the server

I changed the server in my code and now I am seeing Login has failed for user 'Redacted'. Any idea on how to fix this?

Error:

```
 E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\app.js:36
            throw err;
            ^
    ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
        at ConnectionError (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
        at Parser.<anonymous> (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1171:51)
        at Parser.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at Readable.<anonymous> (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
        at Readable.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at addChunk (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:298:12)
        at readableAddChunk (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:280:11)
        at Readable.push (E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:241:10)
        at E:\ExpressServer\kagetruckroutingappServer\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\from.js:49:29
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>) {
      code: 'ELOGIN'
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! kagetruckroutingappserver@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the kagetruckroutingappserver@0.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris.kretman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-29T12_50_43_835Z-debug.log
```

Code:

```
 var Connection = require('tedious').Connection; 
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
    console.log('start')
    var config = {
      server: 'localhost.database.windows.net',  //update me
            authentication: {
                type: 'default',
                options: {
                    userName: 'redacted', //update me
                    password: 'redacted' //update me
                }
            },
            options: {
                // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
                encrypt: true,
                database: 'master'  //update me
            }
    }
        var connection = new Connection(config);  
        console.log('after connection variable')
        connection.connect();
        console.log('after connect')
        connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
          if (err) {
            console.log('Connection Failed');
            throw err;
          } 
            // If no error, then good to proceed.
            console.log("Connected");  
            
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but I was facing this issue yesterday and was able to fix it by changing `encrypt` to `false`:

Example:

```
options: {
  encrypt: false,
}
```

Comment: Maybe for him but i was facing the same issue and this line fixed it, thank you so much @Mohammed Saber

Comment: Glad I was able to save someone from this "tedious" error xD

Comment: Man! you have no idea how much i hated it, it was a constant headache, thank you very very much!